# Milah in Hospital

Tags: halacha, medicine, mistakes, brit-milah

Scenario: a child is born and his parents are not religious. They circumcise him in the hospital as part of neonatal care.

If he becomes religious later in life, or if his parents become religious while he is young, does he require hatafat dam brit?

Comment: I don't think so and I think I remember this somewhere from R' Moshe Feinstein.

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30079/2699

Comment: @Bochur613 seems so - your answer there (+1) has the promise that you will come and update it - nu?

Comment: @Bochur613, the other question was asking whether a hospital circumcision is permissible (*lechatchila*). This one is asking what happens if it was done (=*bedi'avad*). Not a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

In all likelihood he was surgically 'circumcised' before the eighth day, being that the newborns are sent home by day two or three. As such, he is not considered circumcised according to halacha. Even if we would rule with any other leniency such as circumcision at night (probably not in a hospital setting) and circumcision by a nonjew (very likely).

The relevant laws are found in Shulchan Aruch Yoreh De'ah siman 262 siff 1 with Ramma, and siman 264 siff 1 with Ramma.

Comment: or to anybody. how would this answer be different if in fact the child was surgically circumcised on the 8th day by a Jewish doctor, who is not a mohel?

Comment: There is no religious qualification to be a 'mohel'. If one knows how to do mila, they do it and that's it.