# Can a non-Jewish person participate in a bris?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, brit-milah

My best friend is Jewish, and I have been involved in most of the most important events in his life.  I was the best man at his wedding, I celebrated Hanukkah with his family, and I am the "godfather" of his son (although this last item is purely honorary, and if my friend and his now-ex-wife died, I'm sure he would be adopted by one or the other set of grandparents).

I was asked if I wanted to attend the bris, and even to participate in the ceremony, but I just couldn't bring myself to do it - I'm not especially squeamish, but I think seeing the circumcision taking place would have been too much for me to handle.  I politely excused myself from the event.

I'm not sure if it is generally accepted for a non-Jewish person to take part in a bris.  My friend is almost totally non-observant (not only does he cover himself in tattoos and eat whatever he wants regardless of kosher laws, he even celebrates Xmas), so I am wondering if his invitation was possible only because he doesn't care about the accepted practice among observant Jews.

Is it acceptable for a non-Jewish person to participate in a bris?

Comment: Re "I was asked if I wanted to attend the bris, and even to participate…, but… I think seeing the circumcision taking place would have been too much": As to participation, sure. But as to attending -- well, I can't speak for that circumcision, but as far as orthodox ones go, the vast majority IME are done on the lap of someone sitting at floor level without crowds peering, and it's very easy to avoid seeing it done altogether if you prefer not to (indeed most people present don't see it done). Just FYI (in case you get invited to another `:-)`).

Comment: Related (not a duplicate): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30079

Comment: @wad, why rollback to include irrelevant information that distracts from the question?

Comment: @SethJ - I don't think it was irrelevant at all.  I'm not sure why you're spending the day scrutinizing everything I've posted.

Comment: @WadCheber, I'm trying to add value to your posts.

Comment: @SethJ - I appreciate it, but I think the ones you've focused on are just fine as is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this article](http://www.moheldoc.com/files/Parents_Guide_to_Ritual.pdf) regarding the ceremony itself. Near the beginning of the article, it states that non-Jews may attend a brit. As a matter of fact, I invited the CEO of my company, a non-Jew to my 1st son's brit. (It was well-worth the gift that he gave, afterwards, but that wasn't my incentive ;-)

As for participating, IIRC, my rav mentioned that there is no problem with a non-Jew being the *Kvater* - the one who presents the baby coming into the room. (See details on the ceremony). Sometimes this is given to the grandparents, and there have been many cases where the grandparents are not Jewish, but the parents are. The rav could not find any problem with this honor.

I'm not sure if the *sandek* must be Jewish. Refer to [this reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandek#cite_note-Kogen-2) (I'll try to edit in relevant parts from it, later.) Then, again, being a *sandek* would bring you about as close to the baby as the *mohel*, and if your squeamish, you're **definitely** not going to want to be a *sandek*.

Comment: I don't know if the sandek _must_ be Jewish, but it is a huge honor, and I have always heard that it should only be given to someone like a grandfather or a rebbe with a lot of _yirat shamayim_.

Comment: @Daniel To me, this makes sense. Not to discount *Talmidei Chachamim* by any means, but there are many non-Jews with *Yir'at Shamayim* as well ;-) Some, in a sense, more "devoted" than me...

Comment: "Obviously, the mohel must be Jewish" why is this obvious?

Comment: @mevaqesh Hmmm ... Good point. I think there's a M.Y. question on this point. Thanks for the tip (no pun intended.)

Comment: I'm not squeamish, but there are limits to my fortitude.  :)

Comment: @mevaqesh See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30079/may-a-brit-milah-be-performed-by-a-non-jewish-doctor/30080#30080 Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah Siman 264 *Rav Auerbach zt"l told the author of Nishmat Avraham that for a baby who had surgery, it would be best to do hatafat dam brit*

Comment: @sabbahillel why it's that relevant? The surgeon had no intent to do a berit, as to our case which deals with participation inn general. Following the link I see it I'd disputed, not obvious as claimed.

Comment: @mevaqesh Given that the mohel is the shaliach of the father, that may be a consideration as well. http://www.circumcision.net/overview/a-bris-milah-overview  *To qualify as a Mohel one must be a God-fearing, Torah observant Jew, and trained in all of the myriad Jewish laws and medical laws pertaining to Bris Milah.* This is in response to your comment about the mohel not the general question

Comment: @sabbahillel My point was just that things might not be so simple. Citing sources that oversimplify the issue, just shows that there are some sources that hold this.