# Is a circumcision by a doctor but with Jewish ceremony valid?

Tags: brit-milah

I have a friend who is uncertain about his circumcision. He was circumcised at 13 years of age, however not by a "Mohel" but by a common (non-Jewish) medical doctor. However, his father and uncles recited the "Brachot Brit Milah" before and after surgery and made the ceremony.

I wonder if his circumcision is valid?

Comment: See this in [Shulchan Aruch Yore Dea 264, 1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6746)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [May a Brit Milah be performed by a (non-Jewish) doctor?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30079/may-a-brit-milah-be-performed-by-a-non-jewish-doctor)

Comment: Jewish circumcisions are performed at 8 days, not 13 years old. In any case request for rulings in individual circumstances are best handled by a local rabbi and are off-topic for MiYodeya. Your friend will get a much better answer in speaking with someone qualified

Comment: הטפת דם ברית. and following the Shach the Mechaber agrees. A very interesting psak. Many poskim rishonim

Comment: As said before this a question to a real Rabbi, but just for studying Torah. The Rambam (Maimondies) says that even if a monkey commits the Brith the Brith is valid.

I do not know if this is the Halacha at the end (our Halacha does not end with the Rambam :) )