# Does Halakhah permit one to daven a different Nussach in a bind?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, nuschaot

Suppose one's minhag is to daven *Nussach A*; but, one finds oneself in a synagogue, which only has siddurim of *Nussach B*, and one has not committed all of *Nussach A* to memory. He could daven Nussach A and look in the Siddur as well for help when he forgets but it adds confusion to the davening.

Does Halakhhah permit one to daven *Nussach B* in such a situation?

Comment: I would assume its better to daven a real teffilah tjan a mumble jumble. In addition many poskim write that one can alwats switch from sefard to ashknaz since that was the original nusach,also see the back of the Noam Elimelech which surprisingly says this idea as well

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/67057/759

Comment: I am not sure why this is for the sake of convenience. It sounds more like for the sake of Davening properly.

Comment: @GershonGold. Takeh. By convenience I meant that I could still by yoitzei my chiyuv of davening if I try my real nusach - it would just confusing and decrease my kavana.

Comment: @sam But other poskim write that once you switch from Ashkenaz to Sfard (i'm talking about Nusach Sfard, not "Nusach Sephardi") you can't go back

Comment: @SAH ,which poskim, I am referring to Rav Moshe

Comment: @sam the source is chabad's sefer haminhagim. May have been the 1st rebbe of chabad

Comment: Thats Nusach Ari

Comment: @SAH Any Poseik who rules for everyone that only that Poseik's Nusach is the one that you can switch to, should probably be summarily ignored.

Comment: @MarkA. I attempted to make your question more generic (i.e. less of a request for a personal pessaq) and more concise. Please comment in the event that your original intent was lost.

Comment: It's possible that the concept of changing one's nussah tephillah is [entirely muttar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wbg2ZnSbEic).

Comment: I hate to be "that guy", but can you please edit into your question why you think that switching nuschaos should be at all problematic? Why can't a person daven a different nusach just because s/he feels like it?

Comment: I am pretty sure that aderaba to pray with the nusach of the Shul is right.

Comment: @kouty. Why you say that? Even Shemonah Esrei  (bi'lachash)?

Comment: @Mark A I need to verify but may be that if you are praying intentionally some else nussach you are not a part of the tsibbur,  because you are expressing that the Tefila of the tsibbur is not good for you. For the non lachash.  e. g.  the order of alenu,  mizmor shel yom and kave.  or for Monday and Tuesday the order of nefilat appaym and vehurachum is a problem. the nusach of keddusha,  the mizmor shel yom on Shabbat or in chaggim