# Can one sleep in a room with a tefillin bag/tefillin in the room?

Tags: halacha, tefilin, sleep, muktzeh, protective-casing

Can a person sleep in a room with their tefillin bag? Does it matter that the tefillin is in the tefillin bag?
Also, if the answer is no, what can one do on Friday night, if one finds out that inadvertently, they left their tefillin bag on the desk in their room? Is the bag a basis for a davar ha'asur and therefore not be able to be moved. We don't really need gufo or mekomo (we would hypothetically need to get rid of it). 
Any sources would be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya anon! Consider taking the following short [tour](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more. Perhaps [edit](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/68510/edit) in why you think that sleeping in the same room as tefillin might be forbidden. This provides a starting point in looking for a solution.

Comment: This is perhaps better as 2 questions. One about sleeping and one about moving it on shabbos

Answer (score 2):

One is permitted to sleep while one is holding Tefilin in a bag (see [here](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Treating_the_Tefillin_with_Respect), note 12, referencing Kaf Hachayim 44:7). From there it stands to reason it is also fine if the tefilin are on a desk in their bag.

In general one is prohibited from being unclothed in a room with seforim (see for instance [here](http://www.torah.org.il/advanced/weekly-halacha/5762/bo.html)). But it is fine if they are double-covered (e.g., in a bag in a drawer).

Since tefilin are typically "double-wrapped" (the plastic boxes covering them and the bag in which they are stored), it provides an additional reason to be able to sleep in the same room.

Note the Halacha is much stricter for intimate relations in a room with seforim or tefilin (see for instance [here](http://www.torah.org/learning/halacha/S40.html) 40:2).

As always it is better to [CYLOR](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10103/how-do-you-cylor-after-posting-on-judaism-stackexchange-com) for a specific case.

Ps. The mukze status of tfilin on Shabbat is complicated, see [here note 8](http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Kli_SheKol_Melachto_LeIssur) for instance

Comment: This kind of thing is typical if travelling and staying say in a single hotel room. Obviously you can put in lots of layers or wrapping, and possibly a wardrobe may act almost as a separate domain.

Comment: @CashCow I think placing the tefillin in a drawer or closed drawer or your closed suitcase should do the trick. Do I really have to leave my tefillin in the hotel safe while on vacation?