# If eggs have a hechsher, must you still check them for blood spots?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, food, hechsher-certification, inspection, eggs

In general, one checks the yolks of raw eggs for blood spots before using them. However, is it strictly necessary to do this with eggs that have a hechsher on the box? Please provide an authoritative source.

Comment: "In general, we check the yolks of raw eggs for blood spots before using them." Who is "we"?

Comment: Don't you think this would be dependent on what the hechsher is certifying? Why should there be a rule for all hechshers?

Comment: I have never seen this. Is it possible to provide a link to an image?

Comment: @mroll http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3008/2879143016_9bff1e166b_o.jpg . Actually at least half of American egg brands that I see typically have one.

Comment: I would imagine hechsher on eggs is independent from blood in the yolks as hechsher on salad items is to insects.

Comment: @JJLL most well-accepted kashrus agencies don't certify vegetables unless they do not have bugs. Certification of lettuce and other insect-sensitive food items means they do not have to be checked.

Answer (score 6):

First of all raw eggs do not need a hechsher according to [CRC](https://twitter.com/crckosher/status/362688638007517185), [Denver Vaad HaKashrut](http://scrollk.org/guide-to-kashrus-does-it-need-a-hechsher/) and others. The presence of a hechsher on the box does **not** appear to be a factor in two major treatments of the topic.

In a [discussion on blood in eggs](https://oukosher.org/blog/kosher-professionals/eggs-and-blood-spots/), the OU explains that, due to modern production methods, any blood spot found in eggs will never develop into an embryo and according to R Moshe Feinstein do not present a fundamental kashrut problem. As a result, the entire egg is never *assur* and *mei’ikar hadin* removal of the blood spot would suffice. **However** Rav Moshe writes that it is a proper practice to dispose of the entire egg even today, as eggs are not expensive and a person does not incur any significant loss. **Therefore**, the requirement to check each egg remains in effect, as does the requirement to dispose of eggs containing actual blood spots.

On the practicalities, the OU writes that

> - **The accepted practice is to check each individual egg prior to use.**
> - If checking is overly difficult, such as at night on a camping trip, for example, where there is no available good light, one may eat
>     eggs without checking.
> - There is no problem with eating eggs cooked in the shell (boiled or roasted), even though these cannot be checked.
> - If one is in doubt whether the eggs have been checked, it is permitted to eat the food.

In a [detailed article on the topic](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/english/journal/broyde-1.htm), R Michael Broyde expands on the Rema's statement ([SA YD 66:8](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.66.8?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all))

> One does not have to check eggs to see if they have blood spot, as one
>   relies on the fact that most eggs do not; nonetheless, people have the
>   custom to be strict and check the eggs for blood spots when cooking
>   during the day.

and writes

> The crucial question is whether the halachic custom to check eggs must
>   still be observed or whether it is possible to be lenient on this
>   matter and simply not check any eggs generally. The answer to this
>   question is not simple. It might be that one does not have to check
>   eggs for blood spots, but when one is seen, it is still required to
>   remove it according to Jewish law, and **thus, it is prudent to check
>   the eggs before placing them in a situation where it is difficult to
>   remove the blood spot.**
>
> It is possible to conclude that Jewish law does not require that
>   one check eggs for blood spots prior to their use if one purchases
>   grade A or AA eggs from a supermarket in America, although there is a
>   minhag to check eggs, and one who checks for such eggs is in the
>   category of *Hamachmir tavo alav bracha*, (pious conduct for which one
>   is blessed for being strict). No less than six different reasons can
>   be provided to justify the practice of not checking eggs prior to
>   using them:
>
> 1. The United States Department of Agriculture already requires that all eggs be checked for blood spots before they can be sold in a
>      supermarket as grade A or AA eggs. There was never a custom to check
>      twice for blood spots.
> 2. There are virtually never blood spots found in eggs sold in supermarkets in America that are a result of fertilization; thus no
>      biblical violation is ever present even if there is a blood spot in
>      the egg. The custom to check all eggs was limited to a society where
>      not checking might lead to a Torah violation.
> 3. There never was a custom to check for blood spots when all eggs derive from hens raised alone, in which case some authorities rule
>      that even the blood spot itself can be eaten.
> 4. The incidence of blood spots in Grade A or AA eggs sold in the supermarket is less than one in a thousand, and generally one does not
>      have to check for very infrequent rabbinic prohibitions.
> 5. Halacha never required that one check for blood spots; it was a custom, and the custom itself did not apply when it was difficult to
>      check, such as at night. Nowadays, given the way we cook, checking is
>      more difficult in a variety of settings.
> 6. If there is a blood spot in the egg, one will generally see it even after the egg has been opened, and one can remove the blood spot then.
>
> [...]
>
> Even though halacha does not require that one check every grade A or AA
>   egg purchased in a supermarket prior to using it, **there might be
>   prudent reasons why a person might choose to do so, and this explains
>   the common practice of checking eggs found in many Ashkenazi homes.
>   Most significantly, if one sees a blood spot, one must remove it, and
>   it is easier to remove a blood spot prior to adding the egg to food
>   than afterwards.**
>
> **So, too, a person who purchases brown eggs, free
>   range eggs, organic eggs, or eggs sold at a farmers' market, has to
>   check those eggs, and thus it might simply be easier to check all eggs
>   than to monitor what type of egg one is using at any given time.**

As always [CYLOR](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10103/how-do-you-cylor-after-posting-on-judaism-stackexchange-com) for a practical ruling.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'm still wondering if one who has the minhag to check eggs needs to do so if they have a hechsher.

Comment: @SAH I don't really understand why the hechsher would make a difference. Perhaps you could elaborate on why you think it might in the question.