# Are there any halachic issues involved with using jscreen?

Tags: halacha, marriage, medicine, pregnancy-birth, health-safety-shmira

[jscreen.org](https://jscreen.org) is an organization that provides genetic testing for Jews to help potential spouses better know if their children might have the potential to develop different diseases.

The issue is that jscreen gives you all the information. Is this halachically permissible?

Comment: I clicked the link and It got me to the home page. I'm uncertain where to navigate from there to get a sense of what you mean by "gives you all the information" and why you suspect this is a halachic problem. Can you summarize what the concern is?

Comment: @DanF https://jscreen.org/faq/ fourth question down to start

Comment: Why is the question? Why wouldn't this be permissible?

Comment: OK, what's the problem? How is this different than your doctor sending you for a blood test for just cholesterol, but the lab tests for everything including triglic., enzymes, blood cell counts, and all that other stuff occupying a 3 page lab report?

Comment: I've often heard in the name of R' Moshe Feinstein זצ”ל that not only was it muttar to test for disease carriage for  Tay-Sachs (et cetera) but halachically advisable to do so.

Comment: As opposed to [Dor Yesharim](http://doryeshorim.org/)? "*We believe, and the system's resounding global success supports, that in keeping all testing results confidential we eliminate any potential stigmatization of individuals and families.*" http://doryeshorim.org/our-philosophy/

Comment: @Noach unfortunately what you have heard in the name of Reb Moshe is one of his famous contradictions. In his tshuva he wrote like what you mention, but personally he would tell people who asked not to take the test.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt I think the "et cetera" part might be a bit vague. I believe the reason Dor Yesharim only tests for a 'small number' of illnesses is based on Halachic guidance as to how much one needs to take a precaution for unlikely scenarios.  I've heard that as a critique against organizations that test too much, as it's somewhat like a person trying to 'play god'.

Comment: There are rabbis who oppose genetic testing in general (looking for source; pretty sure I saw it in the *Journal of Halacha and Contemporary Society*); would that halachic opinion satisfy this question? IOW, this question's premise is "given that testing without disclosure is accepted, what about testing *with* full disclosure?;" would a general opinion of "no genetic testing at all" be an answer? Related: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2179/5323 especially http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2274/5323

Comment: @user6591, why?

Comment: @Salmononius2, I would think that pikuach nefesh might actually come into play here. If one knows that they are a carrier for a double-recessive disorder, it would behoove them to assess the way in which they fulfill the mitzvah of p'riah ureviah so as not to endanger any future offspring.

Comment: @Noach why did he contradict himself? The whole subject is balancing Tamim Tihye etc (blind faith?) with an allowance to care for yourself. He was more lenient to the general public allowing them less faith and more control, but to his students he expected more faith. I don't recall his wording in the tshvuva, but someone once claimed in the tshvuva he never actually says to do the test, he simply extols the benefits of it. This was said to make it seem like less of a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a student at YU and we were recently encouraged by our Roshei Yeshiva, including Rabbi Kenneth Brander, to undergo screening when JScreen came to our school. I an my fellow students felt very comfortable with JScreen's approach, credibility, and follow-up. Here is what he wrote:

Dear Students,
We believe that all students should undergo genetic testing before marriage, preferably before dating or entering into a serious relationship. Testing gives you the knowledge to make informed decisions which can diminish pain and suffering within our community. YU Roshei Yeshiva encourage students to get tested and to speak to a trained genetic counselor and a knowledgeable halachic authority about any questions they may have.

Please sign up

Kol Tuv,

Rabbi Kenneth Brander

Comment: Hello user12444, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for your first answer! If you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). 

Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

I hope you'll look around and find other Q&A of interest and stay learning with us.

Answer (score 1):

[Yoatzot](http://www.yoatzot.org/taharat-hamishpacha/default.asp?id=619) indeed says that

> **Prenatal testing for genetic or birth defects involves a number of
>   halachic issues.** With most of the available technology, the main
>   concern is not with the procedures themselves - blood tests and
>   ultrasounds - but **with what might be done with the results**.
>
> When testing is done prior to marriage, there is a concern that it
>   could lead to the dissolution of an otherwise appropriate union.
>   Furthermore, misconceptions about the significance of carrier status
>   might lead to difficulty finding a match even if there is no medical
>   reason to fear the birth of an affected child.
>
> [...]
>
> On the other hand, if the prenatal test will lead to an intervention
>   that would be beneficial to the health of the fetus, then there is
>   reason to permit it.

They list jscreen as [one of the organizations they refer people to](http://www.yoatzot.org/life-cycle/?id=641) - but see the others as well who likely have better halachic referrals. I couldn't find halachic advisors on jscreen's site. Note also [Dor Yeshorim](http://doryeshorim.org/) which is mentioned positively [here](http://www.aish.com/ci/sam/48909807.html) and [here](http://www.jewishwomenshealth.org/article.php?article=32) as testing according to R Moshe Feinstein's *psak*.

You might also want to [ask Yoatzot directly](http://www.yoatzot.org/questions-and-answers/ask.asp) as they have halachic advisors and know the topic

Comment: I find this whole subject puzzling. The only reason seems to be that maybe you are "destroying" your shidduch or zivug. People "drop" a shidduch for much less reasons.  Although the dor yeshorim dont tell you what is wrong, you can be quite sure that if a shidduch is refused you and your potential spouse are both carriers of some sort.

Comment: @newcomer I agree. See [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/70319/11501) for another relevant answer with sources showing genetic testing for Ashkenazim is a good idea

Comment: I understand that gerer chasidim do not test.  What we are really looking for  is why it is not a good idea.  My wife's sister and husband are carriers and lost a child to Tay-Sachs. That is before testing existed. Maybe that is why I am biased.  There is also the problem if they are allowed to now live together.  They do.

Answer (score 1):

My Orthodox Rabbi recommended JScreen as they work with a network of reputable Rabbis from around the country. He felt strongly that I should receive the results and that their is no stigmatization regarding shidduchim.

Comment: Ayelet, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for your first answer! If you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). 

Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

I hope you'll look around and find other Q&A of interest and stay learning with us.

Comment: This being said, an anonymous recommendation from a new user is not the strongest. Would you consider asking your rabbi if he would agree to be named? Welcome again and happy to have you here.