# Would a Jew be allowed to partake in pudding that symbolized a divinity

Tags: halacha, food, avodah-zarah

Would a Jew be allowed to partake in the festivities of [Nowruz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowruz) which involves 7 [haft-seen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haft-Seen), 7 different foods that each symbolize a different divinity?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Consider taking the following [short tour](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about the site. Consider also registering your account to unlock more features of the site.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing in a link to the question. If you want to change this or anything else in your question, just [edit](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/71319/edit) it.

Answer (score 1):

There appear to be multiple issues here

- Nowruz appears to be a religious ceremony (Wikipedia: "*remains a holy day for Zoroastrians*") and a Jew is forbidden to participate in non-Jewish religious ceremonies
- one of the seven foods of Haft-Seen is vinegar: if it is made from grapes, vinegar (doubly so in the context of a religious ceremony) [is not kosher](http://revach.net/ask/article.php?id=803) if (1) not certified or (2) handled by non-Jews
- the other dishes, assuming some at least are cooked (like the pudding in the title of your question), would also not be kosher unless specifically prepared according to the laws of kashrut

As always for specific situations you should [CYLOR](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10103/how-do-you-cylor-after-posting-on-judaism-stackexchange-com)

Comment: I dont see anything in the link about wine that is not certified being prohibited.

Comment: "and a Jew is forbidden to participate in non-Jewish religious ceremonies" Since this seems to be the crux of the question, some sources would be appreciated. What is the prohibition, what are its parameters, etc.

Comment: @mevaqesh the link was because "wine merely touched by a non-Jew is forbidden by Rabbinic decree"

Comment: @mbloch so are you agreeing that your claim that without rabbinic supervision wine is forbidden, is source-less?

Comment: @mevaqesh yes it is source-less and correct

Comment: @mbloch It's actually a matter of dispute. Some authorities think at least some modern grape processing facilities are so automated that there is no problem because the grape stuff get pasteurized before anyone touches it.

Comment: This answer is good Lemaasse. Who says that it is prohibed to consume stam yeynam is not source-less. Things that are obvious do not need source. If you says to be Shomer Shabbat and Meniach Tefilin, even without quoting source, it is not sourceless. But the core of the question is the problem of "symbolising a divinity". I do not see how the pudding simbolyse a divinity. What is it?

Comment: Late in the game, but I would point out that even traditional Iranian Jews have haftseen tables. It's not the Kashrut that's the problem..