# Can a person move during Chol HaMoed Pesach?

Tags: passover, chol-hamoed

For financial reasons, I had to move into a suite belonging to a Non-Jew. 3 years later, my landlord has told me I have to move out so his daughter could move in.

However, the days I am expected to move out of my suite to an entirely different suite in a different house are during the Chol HaMoed during Pesach.

My question is this: I understand no melacha is permitted during the first two days and last two days of Pesach, but can a person move during Chol HaMoed?

Asking a local rabbi was “out of the question” because: 
Rabbi #1 is “celebrating Pesach with their family” Rabbi #2 and his family are in Israel, 
Rabbi #3 states: “Because you rented to a Non-Jew, you now face the consequences of your decision. This question will be answered AFTER Pesach. If you decide to move out during the Chol HaMoed, there will be no further communication. Permanently.”

Comment: Ben, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your question here. MiYodeya cannot offer personalized advice because there are too many factors involved in getting to the right answer, instead we encourage you to approach a rabbi who will be able to fully understand your case. This being said, I hope you find more Q&A of interest and stay learning with us!

Comment: Ben, I'm sorry that you've had a frustrating experience with this post. Sometimes it takes more than one try to get the kind of question we can do a great job of answering here. For your original request for spiritual guidance, I echo @mbloch in recommending that you speak to your own spiritual advisor. This isn't just a matter of rules; we simply can't help you the way someone who knows you and your situation can. Regarding the current version of the question, you could improve it by adding more detail about the activities you're assuming are part of moving.

Comment: Moed Katan 2:4.

Answer (score 1):

As DoubleAA indicated the Mishna in [Moed Katan 2:4](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Moed_Katan.2.4?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all) writes

> One may not move belongings from one house to
>   another, but he may move [his belongings] if both houses are in the
>   same courtyard. One may not bring back vessels from the house of the
>   craftsman, but if one is weary about leaving them [lest they get lost]
>   he may move them to another courtyard.

[chabad.org](http://www.chabad.org/holidays/jewishnewyear/template_cdo/aid/4494/jewish/Intermediate-Days.htm) explains and brings a qualification

> The Sages, basing themselves on a number of verses in the Torah, ruled
>   that work is forbidden on chol ha-mo'ed. However, the prohibition of
>   work on chol ha-mo'ed differs from the prohibition on the Festivals
>   which is specifically stated in the Torah. The definition of what
>   constitutes forbidden work and what constitutes permitted work was
>   given to the Sages to determine.
>   [...]
>
> One may not move from one home to another on chol ha-moed unless the
>   new home is in the same complex as the old. If one was living in a
>   rented apartment and wishes to move into his own home, he is permitted
>   to do so, for moving into one's own home is considered to be a source
>   of joy.

As always there are qualifications, see e.g. [Halachipedia](http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Chol_HaMoed#Moving_Houses) (see there fn. 153 and 154)

> Nonetheless, if it’s intolerable to live under present conditions, [or]
>   there’s a loss of money one may certainly move homes.

See also [here](http://matzav.com/the-halachos-of-chol-hamoed/).

As discussed above, please [CYLOR](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10103/how-do-you-cylor-after-posting-on-judaism-stackexchange-com) before taking action personally so that a rav can take into account all parameters.

Comment: Toda rabba everyone. As a beinoni, I am in the process of becoming a ba'al teshuvah. Currently, I cannot CMOLR (Consult My Own Local Rabbi) because I don't know where I fit. I was raised Orthodox but prefer Conservative. So....